# Rank in R - descending order

Tags: r

I am looking to rank data that, in some cases, the larger value has the rank of 1.  I am relatively new to R, but I don't see how I can adjust this setting in the rank function.

```
x <- c(23,45,12,67,34,89)
rank(x)
```

generates:

```
[1] 2 4 1 5 3 6
```

when I want it to be:

```
[1] 5 3 6 2 4 1
```

I assume this is very basic, but any  help you can provide will be very much appreciated.

Answer (score 100):

You could negate `x`:

```
> rank(-x)
[1] 5 3 6 2 4 1
```